# Multiple Windows Updates on Windows Core Server

Tags: windows-update, windows-server

I'm on a Windows 2012 Core Server Machine and doing windows updates through Server Configuration. When It comes back with what updates I want to install I get...

Select an option:
(A)ll updates, (N)o updates or (S)elect a single update?

my management have came to the conclusion that they do not want to install one specific patch.
my issue is that now I have like 15 server that I need to install patches one at a time manually.

I was hoping someone had a good idea/solution to this. Is there any way to install multiple windows updates at the same time on a Windows Core Server?

Answer (score 0):

Install an configure a [Windows Server Update Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx) (WSUS) server to control which updates that are made available to the servers.

> Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) enables information technology administrators to deploy the latest Microsoft product updates to computers that are running the Windows operating system. By using WSUS, administrators can fully manage the distribution of updates that are released through Microsoft Update to computers in their network.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. Most of our server use WSUS. These few are being manually patched.
I will definitely double check on why we don't just add these to our patching cycles. I'm not sure why we haven't done so.
thanks for the quick response Techie007.

Comment: No problem. You can setup different groups in WSUS (and/or define them by Group Policy) for various devices, so that you can apply different patches/rules to those various groups.